# Update Values and show in .cshtml at every specific time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using visual studio serenity template for my aspnet MVC application. For example what I want to do is to generate random values at every 1 second in controller and pass it to cshtml page `<div>`.
Please help me how can I refresh my page at every 1 second.

```
   [RoutePrefix("Dashboard"), Route("{action=index}")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    [Authorize, HttpGet, Route("~/")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

```html
model Serene2.Common.DashboardPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard";
    ViewData["PageId"] = "Dashboard";
}

@section Head {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/morris/morris.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/adminlte/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/adminlte/demo.js"></script>
}

@section ContentHeader {
    <h1>@LocalText.Get("Navigation.Dashboard")<small>@Html.Raw(Texts.Site.Dashboard.ContentDescription)</small></h1>
}
<div class="inner">
                    <p>My Random Value From Controller</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

hey with ajax you can easily achieve that, 
The main issue is such approach will lead to infinite recursive loop so handle with care.Anyway your code should be like below

**1.In cshtml**

```
<p id="pValue"></p>
```

**2. In script**

```
var someRootPath = "@Url.Content("~")";
 (function randomGenerator() {
    $.ajax({
        url: someRootPath + 'Dashboard/GetRandomValue',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#pValue').html(data.someValue);
        },
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(randomGenerator, 1000);
        }
    });
})();
```

and finally

**3.Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetRandomValue()
    {
        return Json(new { someValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hope this will help according to your current scenario.

Comment: not getting result. Now my cshtml looks like <p id="pValue"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(); }, 1000);
    (function randomGenerator() {
        alert('Hello')
        $.ajax({

            url: someRootPath + 'Dashboard/GetRandomValue',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#pValue').html(data.someValue);
            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(randomGenerator, 1000);
            }
                    
        });
        alert('Hello1')
    })();
</script>

Comment: have you checked whether the call going to your application on localhost.Also make sure somerootpath  contains path like "http://localhost/yourappname/".  please see edit my edit to get root path

Comment: Yes call is going to localhost and on somerootpath i have replaced my path as "~/Modules/Dashboard/GetRandomValue" here Modules and Dashboard are my folder and GetRandomValue is the method in DashboardComtroller

Comment: still facing issue.when I insert breakpoint at GetRandomValue It is not hitting.

Comment: what was the issue >

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh your page every second, you could put some javascript on the page like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(); }, 1000);
</script>
```

If you only want to update *part* of the page, you can make an ajax call (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which would point to your controller action - returning only the necessary data. Then, with javascript again, you can modify the parts of the page you find relevant.

Comment: javascript works for me but it refershes complete page. To update part of the page as suggested I have to use ajax but I don't know how can I use that in my case.